# Converting a returned PHP file to XML

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, html-parsing

I am looking for a way to convert a PHP file that I retrieve from a website into XML format using a PHP script.

The returned file I get is:

```
    { "days": [ 
    {"reference":"13L6-A67-1", "dayinit":"4","hourinit":"9"},
    {"reference":"13L6-A67-1", "dayinit":"5","hourinit":"9"} ]}
```

Is there anyway I could convert this to an XML file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <days>
        <day>
            <lesson>
                <reference>13L6-A67-1</reference>
                <hourinit>9</hourinit>

            </lesson>
        </day>
        <day>
            <lesson>
                <reference>13L6-A67-1</reference>

                <hourinit>9</hourinit>

            </lesson>
        </day>
    </days>
```

Preferably so it groups data based on the "dayinit".

Comment: ask yourself: how do you create HTML in PHP? HTML is very similar to XML.

Comment: The first file isn't PHP, it's JSON.

Comment: Use `json_decode` to convert the file into an array, then use an XML library to create the XML elements you want from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the data to an array and loop through it:

```
$test_array = json_decode('{ "days": [
{"reference":"13L6-A67-1", "dayinit":"4","hourinit":"9"},
{"reference":"13L6-A67-1", "dayinit":"5","hourinit":"9"} ]}',true);

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
$xml .= '<days>';

foreach($test_array['days'] as $day) {
    $xml .= '<day>';
        $xml .= '<lesson>';
            $xml .= '<reference>';
                $xml .= $day['reference'];
            $xml .= '</reference>';
            $xml .= '<dayinit>';
                $xml .= $day['reference'];
            $xml .= '</reference>';
            $xml .= '</dayinit>';
                $xml .= $day['hourinit'];
            $xml .= '</hourinit>';
        $xml .= '</lesson>';
    $xml .= '</day>';
}

$xml .= '</days>';
```

Answer (score 0):

What you retrieve is content written in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). You could try to use PHP native functions to transform your content. The following example is rough draw how you could approach your solution.

First, fetch and decode JSON ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)):

```
$json = '...'; // JSON content
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then, use the XML Parser ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.xml.php)) to render your `$data` into XML:

```
// Something like
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse($xml_parser, $data);
```